# 401 redirect magically results in a 302 redirect

Tags: php, redirect, header, laravel

I'm using the `Redirect` class to send non-logged-in users to the login page, with a **401** status code:

```
return Redirect::to('login', 401);
```

This sends the correct location header, but the status code is set to **302**.

---

I've traced it all the way to the base `Response` class in

> laravel/vendor/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php

and it's calling:

```
$this->setStatusCode($status);
```

with the correct **401** code.

---

I also tried dumping the object:

```
var_dump( Redirect::to('login', 401)->foundation );
```

and I can see the protected `statusCode` property is correctly set to **401**.

---

Still, the generated response's HTTP status code is set to **302**.

What gives? Am I using it wrong?

---

**P.S.** I also [posted this on Laravel's forums](http://forums.laravel.com/viewtopic.php?id=3579), to no avail.

Comment: What OS (and server) are you working on?

Comment: are there any other redirects going on AFTER this redirect that aren't obvious? the 401 could work, then a 302 redirect is jumping in after that and doing a redirect... clutching at straws here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not because of laravel, you can reproduce this with just (php 5.4 in windows):

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
header("Location: http://www.google.com");
```

It appears php sets it to 302:

```
$ php-cgi "test.php"
Status: 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://www.google.com
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

In PHP source code main/SAPI.C:

```
} else if (!STRCASECMP(header_line, "Location")) {
    if ((SG(sapi_headers).http_response_code < 300 ||
        SG(sapi_headers).http_response_code > 307) &&
        SG(sapi_headers).http_response_code != 201) {
        /* Return a Found Redirect if one is not already specified */
        if (http_response_code) { /* user specified redirect code */
            sapi_update_response_code(http_response_code TSRMLS_CC);
        } else if (SG(request_info).proto_num > 1000 && 
           SG(request_info).request_method && 
           strcmp(SG(request_info).request_method, "HEAD") &&
           strcmp(SG(request_info).request_method, "GET")) {
            sapi_update_response_code(303 TSRMLS_CC);
        } else {
            sapi_update_response_code(302 TSRMLS_CC);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, when you do `header()` with `"Location"`, the http status code is modified to 302

You can make it work if you do it the other way around:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.google.com");
header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
```

This will give:

```
$ php-cgi "test.php"
Status: 401 Unauthorized
Location: http://www.google.com
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

But laravel sets the location after setting status, so the status is set back to 302 anyway. But this is a moot point, even if you successfully set status to 401 with a location header, the redirect is not followed by browsers.

Comment: +1 Thanks. Is there any other way to work around this? I want unauthorized users to be redirected to the login page, but I also need my AJAX requests to know when the user has logged out (I'm using a method similar to what [Ben Nadel](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2228-Some-Thoughts-On-Handling-401-Unauthorized-Errors-With-jQuery.htm) outlines here).

Comment: @JosephSilber jQuery slaps the X-Requested-With header on the request to let you know it was made with ajax. You can then have 401 status for ajax, and a redirect status for a conventional request

Comment: I thought about that, but have read somewhere that they're planning on dropping it. Couldn't find a source now. Could you confirm either way?

Comment: @JosephSilber can't find anything about that by googling, it seems insane though. All/most ajax libraries slap that header and it's extremely useful because ajax requests work very differently, for instance redirects don't make sense when responding to ajax requests.

Comment: Well, then I must have been hallucinating at one point in the past. Anyhow, I adopted this solution and it works flawlessly. Thanks again.

Comment: For the record, [angular.js dropped this header](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3a75b1124d062f64093a90b26630938558909e8d) about a year ago.

Comment: Well, I never thought about PHP did this.

Answer (score 4):

Browsers will not let you do this; You cannot redirect with a 401.

Answer (score 1):

I followed it even farther... down until `public function sendHeaders()` in `laravel/vendor/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php`... where it generates the final status header

```
   // status
    Header(sprintf('HTTP/%s %s %s', $this->version, $this->statusCode, $this->statusText));
```

...and it was still 401, of course.

*Then* it dawned to me. *You can't redirect with a 401*, which is a ClientError.

(It would also fail the `isRedirect` test stated in the same `Response.php` file. `mod_php` will fix it for you to 302 as soon as you send a `Location` (because by default the status is 200, so it needs be updated. PHP doesn't check whether it has been already updated to something else).

Comment: +1 for going all the way down the rabbit hole on this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others, there's no such a thing as a 401 redirect. The reason I got hooked into this was because [I need non-AJAX users to be redirected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483937#comments-13484117), but [AJAX requests should get a 401](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2228-Some-Thoughts-On-Handling-401-Unauthorized-Errors-With-jQuery.htm).

---

If you find yourself in a similar situation, here's what I ended up using:

```
return Request::ajax() ?
         Response::make('', 401, array('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized')) :
         Redirect::to('login', 302);
```

This uses Laravel's methods for handling headers.

---

If you're using vanilla PHP, use this:

```
$is_ajax_request = ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest';

$is_ajax_request ?
    header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized') :
    header('Location: http://site.com/login');

exit;
```