# Redirect gives 302Found Error in Laravel4

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-4

I have a Laravel4 project in which I use Facebook PHP SDK.

In that I use the code to redirect to facebook for auth

```
    $facebook = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));
    $params = array(
        'redirect_uri' => url('/fbcallback'),
        'scope' => 'email',
    );
    return Redirect::to($facebook->getLoginUrl($params));
```

It was all okay when the project was in local (development) environment but as soon as I deployed the code to (client's) production server (Shared Hosting, cPanel) I started getting errors in redirection.

First I thought it was Facebook but then I realized the errors occur in every redirection that uses the `Redirect::to()` or similar.

The error is a page 
[image: the error]

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that the Laravel Redirector class defines the status code 302 as default value ([source](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Routing.Redirector.html)) which might be the problem here, check out this SO post for details and examples that might help you figure it out:

[401 redirect magically results in a 302 redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483937/401-redirect-magically-results-in-a-302-redirect)

Comment: My problem is not 302 redirect. Apache is not doing a 302 redirect instead showing the status page.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of the Redirect::to()

```
return Response::make()->header( 'Location', (string)$facebook->getLoginUrl($params) );
```

Comment: Don't know why but this works. Can you please help me with the reason.

Comment: I actually faced a similar scenario! I think it has to do more with casting the url into a string rather than the method for redirecting